# replace every other space with new line

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have strings like this:

```
a <- "this string has an even number of words"
b <- "this string doesn't have an even number of words"
```

I want to replace every other space with a new line. So the output would look like this...

```
myfunc(a)
# "this string\nhas an\neven number\nof words"
myfunc(b)
# "this string\ndoesn't have\nan even\nnumber of\nwords"
```

I've accomplished this by doing a `strsplit`, `paste`-ing a newline on even numbered words, then `paste(a, collapse=" ")` them back together into one string. Is there a regular expression to use with `gsub` that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Jota suggested a simple and concise way:

```
myfunc  = function(x) gsub("( \\S+) ", "\\1\n", x)       # Jota's    
myfunc2 = function(x) gsub("([^ ]+ [^ ]+) ", "\\1\n", x) # my idea

lapply(list(a,b), myfunc)


[[1]]
[1] "this string\nhas an\neven number\nof words"

[[2]]
[1] "this string\ndoesn't have\nan even\nnumber of\nwords"
```

*How it works.* The idea of `"([^ ]+ [^ ]+) "` regex is (1) "find two sequences of words/nonspaces with a space between them and a space after them" and (2) "replace the trailing space with a newline".

@Jota's `"( \\S+) "` is trickier -- it finds any word with a space before and after it and then replaces the trailing space with a newline. This works because the first word that is caught by this is the second word of the string; and the next word caught by it is not the third (since we have already "consumed"/looked at the space in front of the third word when handling the second word), but rather the fourth; and so on.

*Oh, and some basic regex stuff.*

- `[^xyz]` means any single char except the chars x, y, and z.
- `\\s` is a space, while `\\S` is anything but a space
- `x+` means `x` one or more times
- `(x)` "captures" `x`, allowing for reference in the replacement, like `\\1`

Comment: Hey, would you mind explaining the regex so I get it for next time? Thanks!